# How to use subquery in OFFSET in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, median

I have been trying to solve this problem : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20/problem?isFullScreen=true

It states to find the median, but everytime I am ending up with syntax error or runtime error.

```
SELECT ROUND(LAT_N, 4)
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LAT_N
LIMIT 1 OFFSET (
  SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN COUNT(LAT_N) % 2 <> 0 THEN COUNT(LAT_N) / 2
      ELSE (COUNT(LAT_N) - 1) / 2
    END
  FROM STATION
);
```

This is the solution that I have worked upon. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure you can put a `SELECT` expression in an `OFFSET` clause.  However, there might be an alternative - see https://gist.github.com/vlasky/d98a7d162582c32c541157a5abbf59b8

Comment: 'LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:

Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.

Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.' -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: Questions should be self contained - please add table definition and sample data as text.

Comment: A similar query works in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROUND(s.LAT_N, 4) 
FROM STATION s 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(LAT_N) FROM STATION WHERE s.LAT_N > LAT_N) = 
      (SELECT COUNT(LAT_N) FROM STATION WHERE s.LAT_N < LAT_N)
```